# Titanium Mobile Controller troubles

Tags: javascript, titanium, javascript-objects

Ok so Im working on a mobile app and I wanna make sure my structure is right so I can continue to add more complex things.

Basicaly I am asking if this is the best way to do this.

this is my controller:

```
app.controller.newItem = function(object) {
var item = app.view.newItem();

item.cancel.addEventListener("click", function(){
    item.win.close();
});

item.save.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if ( String(name.value).length > 0){
        var lastInsert = app.model.addItem({ 
            title: item.name.value,
            todo: item.todo.value,
            section: 1,
            placement: 1,
            matrix_id: object.id 
            });
        Ti.App.fireEvent('item_updated', { title: item.name.value, todo: item.todo.value, id: lastInsert, section: '1' });
        item.close();
    }

});
```

}

then this is my view:

```
app.view.newItem = function() {
// create new item window
var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
    title:'Add a New Item',
    backgroundColor:'stripped',
    navBarHidden: false
});
    // navbar buttons
var cancel = Titanium.UI.createButton( {title:'Cancel'} );
var save = Titanium.UI.createButton( {title:'Save', style:Titanium.UI.iPhone.SystemButton.SAVE,} );

// labels and text areas
var name_label = app.ui.label({
    text: "Item Name:",
    top: 35,
    left: 30
});
var name = app.ui.textArea({
    height: name_label.height,
    top: name_label.top + 35
});
var todo_label = app.ui.label({
    text: "Todo:",
    top: name.top + 40,
    left: name_label.left
});
var todo = app.ui.textArea({
    height: 70,
    top: todo_label.top +35
});

//set items
var setItems = function() {
    win.setLeftNavButton(cancel);  
    win.setRightNavButton(save);  
    win.add(name);
    win.add(name_label);
    win.add(todo);
    win.add(todo_label);
    win.open({modal: true, animation: true});
}();  

return {
    win: win,
    cancel: cancel,
    save: save
}
```

}

Should I be adding my event listener in my controller? I really don't want to use the
`item = app.view.newItem();` then `item.save.addEventListener()..` sintax can't I just call them `save.addEventListener` instead of having the `item` in front. I can't cause that would make `save` a global variable right?

Comment: what is your your definition of controller and model (and item)? i am not sure if i understood your code well.

Comment: well I'm not sure what my comtroller should do. I'm adding my event listeners in my controller... Um i didn'y post my model. I basically has functions to handle my database connection. My view has all my objects to display. and the controller... well i know what it's supposed to do but I don't know how to so it. I basically just call the draw functions... and add the even handlers...

Answer (score 0):

I generally put event listeners on buttons when I create the button. Especially when the functions they're executing pertain to information on the view.

```
app.view.newItem = function() {
    // create new item window
    var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
        title:'Add a New Item',
        backgroundColor:'stripped',
        navBarHidden: false
    });

    // navbar buttons
    var cancel = Titanium.UI.createButton({title:'Cancel'});

    cancel.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        win.close();
    });

    var save = Titanium.UI.createButton({title:'Save', style:Titanium.UI.iPhone.SystemButton.SAVE});

    save.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        if (String(name.value).length > 0){
            var lastInsert = app.model.addItem({ 
                title: item.name.value,
                todo: item.todo.value,
                section: 1,
                placement: 1,
                matrix_id: object.id 
                });
            Ti.App.fireEvent('item_updated', { title: item.name.value, todo: item.todo.value, id: lastInsert, section: '1' });
            win.close();
        }
    });

    // labels and text areas
    var name_label = app.ui.label({
        text: "Item Name:",
        top: 35,
        left: 30
    });

    var name = app.ui.textArea({
        height: name_label.height,
        top: name_label.top + 35
    });

    var todo_label = app.ui.label({
        text: "Todo:",
        top: name.top + 40,
        left: name_label.left
    });

    var todo = app.ui.textArea({
        height: 70,
        top: todo_label.top +35
    });

    //set items
    var setItems = function() {
        win.setLeftNavButton(cancel);  
        win.setRightNavButton(save);  
        win.add(name);
        win.add(name_label);
        win.add(todo);
        win.add(todo_label);
        win.open({modal: true, animation: true});
    }();  

    return {
        win: win,
        cancel: cancel,
        save: save
    }
}
```